# Collapsing panels with initial states

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to get my collapsing panels working with an initial state of collapsed (or not). Without the initial state feature, it works fine but when I introduce that, the initial click is goofy, and the indicator icon is inverted. I'm sure this is just a logic puzzle I'm failing to see clearly but the fact is I'm stumped.

Using jQuery and Bootstrap. The code is slightly modified for the purposes of this post, which is why it's in its own function (normally it's an export function with TypeScript but that shouldn't matter here) and the icon is using an icon font so I substituted a '^' for simplicity.

To be clear, the 'icon' should point down when the panel is collapsed, and up when expanded, indicating what action will happen when you click it (as opposed to indicating its current state (that caused some confusion between my engineers and designers, lol!) I need to be able to apply a class of 'collapsed' to the target so it's initial state is collapsed.

http://codepen.io/sinrise/pen/eBoNPE

HTML

```
<div class="container" style="padding-top: 30px;">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading collapse-header" data-target="#test-panel1">Heading</div>
        <div class="panel-body collapsed" id="test-panel1">
          <p>some content</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading collapse-header" data-target="#test-panel2">Heading</div>
        <div class="panel-body" id="test-panel2">
          <p>some content</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>  
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.collapse-header + .collapsed { display: none; }

.collapse-header {
    position: relative;
    &:hover { cursor: pointer; }
    &:after {
        position: absolute;
        font-family: "Sans-serif";
        content: "^";
        transform: rotateZ(0deg);
        right: 15px;
        transition: all 0.5s linear;
    }
    &.rotate-icon {
        &:after {
            transform: rotateZ(180deg);
            transition: all 0.5s linear;
        }
    }
}
```

JS/jQuery

```
function setCollapsableHeaders() {
    $.each($(".collapse-header"), function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        var tar = $($this.attr("data-target"));
        $this.on("click", function () {
            $this.toggleClass("rotate-icon");
            tar.toggleClass("collapsed");
            tar.animate({
                height: "toggle",
                paddingTop: "toggle",
                paddingBottom: "toggle"
            }, 500, function () {
            });
        });
    });
};

$(function(){
  setCollapsableHeaders();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

so as you have expected, it was just a small change to the code. :)

here is a working one (except for the icon, you should place whatever icon you want)
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZBZbEa

and here is the whole snippet for reference

```
function setCollapsableHeaders() {
$.each($(".collapse-header"), function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    var tar = $($this.attr("data-target"));
    $this.on("click", function () {
        $this.toggleClass("rotate-icon");
        //tar.toggleClass("collapsed");
        tar.animate({
            height: "toggle",
            paddingTop: "toggle",
            paddingBottom: "toggle"
        }, 500, function () {
        });
    });
});
};

$(function(){
      setCollapsableHeaders();
});
```

the only changed this is this commented line

```
//tar.toggleClass("collapsed");
```

because initially you were messing up the logic and then ding the same thing with code, so your first click was actually setting the correct class (either added or removed) then subsequent clicks were fine.

I hope this helps

Comment: Thanks! That's almost it. Unfortunately, your solution doesn't fix the initial collapsed state issue. The arrow is pointing the wrong way on the panel that is collapsed initially...

Comment: this is not an issue to fix because the way you are adding the icon by is kinda static. "^". so I think it's beyond the solution ability (maybe there is a better fix to get this arrow correct, but I can't think of it) :)

Comment: cause you are on the CSS level assigning the "^" character, so regardless of the panel state, it will follow your command and assign it.  consider this example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bBJVgg all panels are open so your charachter "^" is pointing correctly. hope you get my point.

Comment: Thanks again. I posted my solution below. You helped me figure out my mistake. I updated the pen so you can see the working example. I used a 'v' and a '^' because the key is to have different icons/characters for the different initial state.

Comment: This is exactly what I was trying to say, that you need to modify the icon logic, not just handle it with only "^"  in use. Glade that you could fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**:

Thanks to everyone for your input. It helped me figure out how to solve this. So the icon thing caused some confusion. I'm using a glyphicon chevron. So, what I did instead was to create a couple of CSS classes:

```
.collapse-icon-up:after {
    content: "\E602";
}

.collapse-icon-down:after {
    content: "\E601";
}
```

Which uses a different glyphicon depending on the initial state. This works well with my js and CSS animation toggles. I commented out:

```
tar.toggleClass("collapsed");
```

as suggested by Mohammed ElSayed. Thank you :)

Then I added:

```
if (tar.hasClass("collapsed")) {
    $this.addClass("collapse-icon-down");
} else {
    $this.addClass("collapse-icon-up");
}
```

To the js each loop in order to set the initial direction of the icon.

As I suspected, it was something simple and just a logic puzzle. It seems to be working perfectly now! Thanks again for your help! :D